# How would i halt my code in the little section and my if and else statements arent working

Tags: javascript

I want my code to halt/stop/break where i put the `return;` and i want it to halt, i have tried using `break` if anyone could help me that would be appreciated, i am pretty new to Javascript so don't be upset if i dont get everything right the first time :D anyhelp would be very appreciated.

```
function InitAll() {
    var name = prompt("What is your name?", "");
    document.write("Hello, " + name + " this is a little Javascript Activity!");
    var PromptAnswer = prompt("So, " + name + " do you like to play Soccer?", "");
    if (PromptAnswer == "yes" || "Yes" || "Yes!" || "yes!" || "yeah" || "yeah!" || "Yeah!") {
        document.write("Cool, that's awesome, i play Soccer too!");
        var PromptAnswer2 = prompt("Well, even some people play Soccer and don't like it, do you like soccer?", "");
        if (PromptAnswer2 == "yes" || "Yes" || "Yes!" || "yes!" || "yeah" || "yeah!" || "Yeah!") {
            document.write("Yeah, its pretty fun.");
        }
        if (PromptAnswer2 == "") {
            return;
        }
        else {
            document.write("Well, that's really too bad, but i guess if you don't like it, you dont like it. :D");
        }
    }
    else {
        var PromptAnswer3 = prompt("Well, what sports do you like to play?", "");
        if (PromptAnswer3 == "football" || "Football") {
            document.write("Haha yeah, football is pretty awesome, even though i'm a Javascript Script, my Creator can throw football pretty well. :D");
        }
        else {
            document.write(PromptAnswer3 + " is pretty cool.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code.

The prompt function can return `null` so you probably want to change this:

```
    if (PromptAnswer2 == "") {
        return;
```

to this:

```
    if (!PromptAnswer2) {
        return;
    }
```

The `return` statement will finish the execution of that function, returning control back to whatever called the function.

That will check `PromptAnswer2` for `null`, `""`, `undefined` and several other things too.

Secondly, statements like this:

```
if (PromptAnswer == "yes" || "Yes" || "Yes!" || "yes!" || "yeah" || "yeah!" || "Yeah!")
```

must be written like this:

```
if (PromptAnswer == "yes" || PromptAnswer == "Yes" || PromptAnswer == "Yes!" || PromptAnswer == "yes!" || PromptAnswer == "yeah" || PromptAnswer == "yeah!" || PromptAnswer == "Yeah!")
```

or perhaps even better to remove the different case possibilities:

```
PromptAnswer = PromptAnswer.toLowerCase();
if (PromptAnswer == "yes" || PromptAnswer == "yes!" || PromptAnswer == "yeah" || PromptAnswer == "yeah!")
```

or using regular expressions:

```
if (PromptAnswer.match(/^(yes|yeah)!?$/i))
```

Third, you may want to know that `document.write()` on a fully loaded document will clear the current document and start writing a new document.  It is usually not what one wants to do in event handling javascript.

Comment: +1, but I think it should be `PromptAnswer2 === ""` - never know what kind of wild conversions may happen

Comment: @AdamRackis - my recommendation was `if (!PromptAnswer2)` because they need to check for null too.

Comment: Hmm, any recommendations, im new to javascripting so, maybe i could use something like add id's to a paragraph and do innerHTML= or what? Your answer was very clear, tyvm.

Comment: Nvm i fixed it, i used an alert, or else i would've used something like DOM Manipulation.